# How to resize a widget to fit a list Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a problem. There is a list and Flexible, which should expand according to the size of the list, but now with mine the list is decreasing, but there is no container itself. How can I make the container fit the length of the list and change constantly instead of being static? It's just that if I remove Container from Flexible, then I will have a list without a background color.

```
Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24, right: 24),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 178),
            const BackStepWidget(text: 'Select Language'),
            const SizedBox(height: 30),
            Container(
              width: size.width,
              // height: 65,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(24),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(24)),
                  color: constants.Colors.greyDark),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 16, right: 16, top: 16, bottom: 13),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                        child: TextFormField(
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: constants.Colors.greyLight,
                          hintText: 'Search',
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: constants.Colors.white),
                          prefixIcon: Icon(
                            Icons.search,
                            color: constants.Colors.white,
                          ),
                          suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_voice,
                              color: constants.Colors.white),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                          )),
                    )),
                    const SizedBox(width: 14),
                    const Text('Cancel',
                        style: constants.Styles.smallBookTextStyleWhite)
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: Container(
                width: size.width,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(24),
                        bottomRight: Radius.circular(24)),
                    color: constants.Colors.greyDark),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
                  child: MediaQuery.removePadding(
                    context: context,
                    removeTop: true,
                    child: ListView.separated(
                        separatorBuilder: ((context, index) => Divider(
                            height: 2,
                            color: constants.Colors.white.withOpacity(0.2))),
                        itemCount: language.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.only(top: 9, bottom: 10),
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    language[index],
                                    style: constants
                                        .Styles.smallBoldTextStyleWhite,
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    language[index],
                                    style: constants
                                        .Styles.smallerBookTextStyleWhite,
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            )),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a ListView.Separated inside the Container. Thing is, ListView's by default have an **infinite** height...

Go ahead and give your ListView the shrinkWrap property, like this:

```
ListView.separated(
   shrinkWrap: true,
   (...)
)
```

This will shrink the ListView to only be the height of it's children's combined heights!

Good luck xx